# Terraria only count second night with Night Sensor

Tags: terraria

So I have a Night Sensor, and an Announcement Box with a message I want to display at the start of the second night after starting, and the second night ONLY.

I've tried using Logic Gates but they always fire at both nights.

How can I manage this?